# React in the program on the signal change

Tags: delphi, events, event-handling, delphi-7

I would like to react in the program (VCL) on the signal change of a 
Boolean variable (call the different functions, for example- start/stop the measurement). How can I realize it? Is there an another way without timer?

I use Delphi 7 and I work with Delphi for just short time.

Comment: If your *variable* can be a *property* then you can fire an event from the property setter if the value to set is different than the current value of the property

Comment: @Sir Rufo I have the varible as property: `procedure SetCanStart(const Value: boolean);
function GetCanStart: boolean; 
property CanStart: boolean read GetCanStart write SetCanStart;`

Comment: You can't fire events when variables change. You need to encapsulate the variable somehow. Property is one way. A procedure another.

Comment: @David Heffernan Could you explain this, please? How I wrote, I work with Delphi just short time.

Comment: What is there to explain. Encapsulate?

Comment: @genakust *variable* and *property* are different things. Your question mentioned *variable* but in the comment you state that it is a *property*. My answer shows a solution where the *property* encapsulates a *field* (which is the name for a *variable* inside a class definition)

Comment: @genakust You can track or intercept a *property* via the *getter/setter* methods which you cannot with a *variable* or a *field*.

Comment: @Sir Rufo, Thank you for your explanation! Your example works and and that's what I intend.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a setter method for the property and check inside that setter if the new value is different from the current value.

If so, then set the value and fire an event (here the `OnCanStartChanged`)

```
uses
  Classes;

type
  TFoo = class
  private
    FCanStart         : Boolean;
    FOnCanStartChanged: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetCanStart( const Value: Boolean );
    procedure SetOnCanStartChanged( const Value: TNotifyEvent );
  protected
    procedure DoCanStartChanged( ); virtual;
  public
    property CanStart         : Boolean read FCanStart write SetCanStart;
    property OnCanStartChanged: TNotifyEvent read FOnCanStartChanged write SetOnCanStartChanged;
  end;

  { TFoo }

procedure TFoo.DoCanStartChanged;
begin
  if Assigned( FOnCanStartChanged )
  then
    FOnCanStartChanged( Self );
end;

procedure TFoo.SetCanStart( const Value: Boolean );
begin
  if FCanStart <> Value
  then
    begin
      FCanStart := Value;
      DoCanStartChanged( );
    end;
end;

procedure TFoo.SetOnCanStartChanged( const Value: TNotifyEvent );
begin
  FOnCanStartChanged := Value;
end;
```

Comment: thank you very mach for this example. I'm trying to understand how it works.

Comment: It will call the method you have passed to OnCanStartChanged property if you assign a different value than the current to CanStart property. Thats all